# Finding every record of specific string in database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with the column "endpointid" in a lot of tables. I am looking for a search function that would find every table containing a specific endpointid in order to write a query to delete that endpoint. I have tried a delete function to delete it from all tables but that is not working properly since a specific endpointid might not be in all tables. I know the following query gives all tables with the column name:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where lower(column_name) like lower('%endpointid%');
```

How can I extend that query to search for a specific record of endpointid?

Comment: do you want to **drop** such columns ?

Comment: not drop the columns but delete the rows with the endpointid I am searching for

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to delete rows with a specific endpointid value:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest (
    endpointid NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO mytest VALUES ( 1 );
INSERT INTO mytest VALUES ( 2 );

DECLARE
    ep NUMBER := 2;
BEGIN
    FOR t_rec IN (
        SELECT
            table_name
        FROM
            all_tab_columns
        WHERE
            lower(column_name) LIKE lower('%endpointid%')
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from '
                          || t_rec.table_name
                          || ' where endpointid = :1'
            USING ep;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Note that if these tables have foreign key relationships, this may fail, as it does not take into account the ordering of the table references. If that is needed, then you would need to structure your metatada query to find those relationships.

Comment: When I ran the query in my DB I changed line 21 to the endpointid I was searching for but I got the error "starting at line 8:" "ORA- 00942: table or view does not exist". I added the line "alter session set current_schema = myschema;" to the beginning of the code so am unsure why I am still receiving that error

Comment: print out the value of t_rec.table_name and see what it is.  Is it in a different schema than the user that is running the query?  If so, it may be a grant/rights issue.  You either need to execute the script with a user that has access to all the tables, or provide your username access to those tables.

Comment: In this answer be sure to protect against injectable table names. Consider... CREATE TABLE " mytest where  :1 is not null -- "